# Save string to to PDF: Charset encoding issue?

Tags: pdf, character-encoding

I'm trying to save a string as a file (pdf), but it seems the encoding isn't what it seems.

I'm wondering if anyone knows what char encoding or converting is required for the following snippet?

```
%PDF-1.3
%����
1 0 obj
<</Title (Faktura 0)/Producer (ComponentOne C1Pdf)/CreationDate (D:20210122122339+01'00')/ModDate (D:20210122122339+01'00')>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Length 1789/Filter /FlateDecode>>stream
x��w6PH/��2P\00� w=S�r ����LM|�c��^.css=K##3V(J��
...more pdf code.
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to save a string as a file (pdf)"* - if you already have it as a string (and not some byte array), chances are that you have already damaged its data. PDF is a binary format, and reading binary data into a string depending on the encoding assumed in that reading can damage the binary data.

Comment: @mkl I do have the option of receiving the data as a array buffer.

Comment: @mkl Thank you. I just received a array buffer and then wrote to file. It's working now! Post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Great that it's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF is a binary format, and reading binary data into a string depending on the encoding assumed in that reading can damage the binary data.

Thus, if possible, *don't retrieve the data as a string but instead as a byte array or byte buffer* and store these bytes as they are.

As you confirmed in a comment,

> I just received a array buffer and then wrote to file. It's working now!